# Как правильно набирать кавычки, скобки?

Tags: текст, клавиатура, печать, кавычки

Недавно начал изучать программирование, а с ним и слепую печать. И возник вопрос.

Покажу на примере функции print() из Python.

Раньше (Не слепой метод печати) я набирал сначала:

```
print('')
```

А затем нажимал два раза на клавишу "Left" и писал то, что нужно, например:

```
print('Hello World!')
```

Но теперь(Когда печатую в 10 пальцев) нужно все символы набирать по порядку? То есть "print", затем скобка, кавычка, текст("Hello World!"), кывычка и наконец скобка?

ИЛИ же печатать, как печатал до этого?

Comment: Попробуйте оба варианта, и решите для себя, что лучше. Я вообще обычно пишу `print()`<влево>`''`<влево>`Hello World!`. Можно еще настроить IDE, чтобы она сама закрывала скобки и кавычки...

Comment: Здесь нет "нужно". Как удобно, так и печатайте. Главное, чтобы на выходе был хороший правильный код

Comment: без разницы, главное итог

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит попробовать оба варианта и выбрать более удобный.